Declarative router conversion for flutter
anyone know how to change this declarative example from go_router to auto_route? i want nested navigation in bottomsheet and trying to implement this package smooth_sheets
the example using go_router with shell_router, can refer the package link.
final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/a',
  routes: [
    // We use ShellRoute to create a Navigator
    // that will be used for nested navigation in the sheet.
    ShellRoute(
      // Do not forget this line!
      observers: [transitionObserver],
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return _ExampleHome(nestedNavigator: child);
  },
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/a',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        // Use DraggableNavigationSheetPage for a draggable page.
        // If the page contains scrollable widget(s), consider using
        // ScrollableNavigationSheetPage instead.
        return DraggableNavigationSheetPage(
          key: state.pageKey,
          child: const _ExampleSheetContent(
            title: '/a',
            size: 0.5,
            destinations: ['/a/details', '/b'],
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return DraggableNavigationSheetPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: const _ExampleSheetContent(
                title: '/a/details',
                size: 0.75,
                destinations: ['/a/details/info'],
              ),
            );
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'info',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                return DraggableNavigationSheetPage(
                  key: state.pageKey,
                  child: const _ExampleSheetContent(
                    title: '/a/details/info',
                    size: 1.0,
                    destinations: ['/a', '/b', '/b/details'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
          ],
        ),
        [...]
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

My attempt on auto_route
onTap: () => showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isDismissible: true,
              builder: (context) {
                return const AddressBottomsheet();
           },
          ),

 class _AddressBottomsheetState extends State<AddressBottomsheet> {
  final transitionObserver = NavigationSheetTransitionObserver();
  String province = "";
  String city = "";
  String district = "";
  @override
  Widget build(context) => AutoRouter.declarative(
    // use AutoRouter.declarative
    navigatorObservers: () => [transitionObserver],
    onNavigate: (r) => print("$r"),
    onPopRoute: (route, results) => print("$route & $results"),
    routes: (_) {
      // Declaratively define your routes here
      return [
        ProvincePage(onSelected: (v) {
        setState(() {
            province: v;
          });
        }),
        if(province.isNotEmpty)
        CityPage(onSelected: (v) {
        setState(() {
            city: v;
          });
        }),
        if(province.isNotEmpty)
        DistrictPage(onSelected: (v) {
        setState(() {
            district: v;
          });
        }),
      ];
    },
  );
}

but get error. bottomsheet open up with red screen. *this declarative is not set during the main config but one of the screen.
RouteData operation requested with a context that does not include an RouteData.
The context used to retrieve the RouteData must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a AutoRoutePage.

